# Update column updated_at in magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2

I want to create some some custom action **update extension attribute of order**.
Also I need to reflect that change in order column **updated_at**

This is my code but for now i can see that i cant update this column directly.

```
$order->setUpdatedAt('2023-04-19 09:05:08');
$this->orderRepository->save($order);
```

So my question is how can I update column update_at in order ?